# Floating point exception (core dumped) while opening Packet Tracer

Tags: root

I installed Cisco packet tracer on ubuntu 18.04 using this link. It works perfectly fine on "Guest session" but does not login to my cisco account. It throws this error whenever I try to login and asks to force quit:

```
./libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by ./PacketTracer7)
Floating point exception (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try to install Microsoft fonts, see instruction under the link below:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Microsoft_fonts

Answer (score 0):

On my Ubuntu 16.04.6, I found an answer by doing:

```
walt@bat:~(0)$ locate libcrypto.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
...
walt@bat:~(0)$ dpkg -S /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
libssl1.0.0:amd64: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
walt@bat:~(0)$ apt-cache search libssl1.0.0
libssl1.0.0 - Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - shared libraries
libssl1.0.0-dbg - Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - debug information
```

YMMV, but it looks like you need to install `libssl1.0.0` and `libssl1,0,0-dbg`.

OR, if you already have those packages installed, and, since PacketTracer is complaining about "`./libcrypto.so.1.0.0`" (indicating it wants to find `libcrypto.so.1.0.0` in the current directory?), maybe you should

```
ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 .
```

(or wherever the `locate` told you your `libcrypto` is).

Comment: still not working and I am using Ubuntu 19.10